# Extend class to a multiple class instances Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, prototype

I have `UserModel` class which has static methods, and I want to extend or inherit to multiple class instances.

**UserModel.js**

```
const tableName = "Users";
const primaryKey = "UserID";
const secondaryTables = [{ id: "RoleID", name: "Roles", relation: " INNER JOIN " }];
const getterModel = new GettersModel(tableName, primaryKey, secondaryTables);
const deleteModel = new DeleteModel(tableName, primaryKey);

class UserModel {

    constructor() {

    }

    static async insertUser({ username, password, roleId }) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(UserModel, getterModel);
Object.setPrototypeOf(UserModel, deleteModel);
```

**DeleteModel.js**

```
class DeleteModel {
    constructor(tableName, primaryKey) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;

    }
     async deleteRow(id) {

        try {
            const result = await mysql_conn.delete(this.tableName, `where 
                                  ${this.primaryKey}=?`, [id]);
            return result;

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**UserService.js**

```
async function deleteUser(userID) {

        let ret = await UserModel.deleteRow(userID);

        if (ret == false) {
            return { status: false }
        } else {
            return { status: true }
        }

}
```

But the problem is `GettersModel` gets replaced by the prototype of `DeleteModel` when setting this:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(UserModel, getterModel);
Object.setPrototypeOf(UserModel, deleteModel);
```

And also, there's a warning in MDN website about `.setPrototypeOf()`:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

> **Warning**: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, **currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine**. In addition, the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in the Object.setPrototypeOf(...) statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered.
>
> Because this feature is a part of the language, it is still the **burden
> on engine developers to implement that feature performantly** (ideally).
> Until engine developers address this issue, if you are concerned about
> performance, you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object.
> Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using
> Object.create().

So how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use inheritance here. The `UserModel` class should *use* the `deleteModel` instance.

To expose `UserModel.deleteRow`, you can use

```
class UserModel {
    constructor() {…}
    static async insertUser(…) { … }
    
    static deleteRow = deleteModel.deleteRow.bind(deleteModel)
}
```

or

```
class UserModel {
    constructor() {…}
    static async insertUser(…) { … }
}
UserModel.deleteRow = deleteModel.deleteRow.bind(deleteModel);
```

However, I would suggest that you should not expose a `deleteRow` method on your `UserModel` - what is a row? You should instead write

```
class UserModel {
    constructor() {…}
    static async insertUser(…) { … }
    
    static async deleteUser(userID) {
        return {status: await deleteModel.deleteRow(userID)};
    }
}
```